# Print with PDFBox

Tags: printing, pdfbox

I`m new here and have a Problem with PDFBox.
I`m trying to print a single PDF Document, but it doesn`t work so far.
I found some examples in the internet, but don`t get it run, so I hope someone here has an idea, where my mystake is.
The Code I have so far is:

```
File datei = new File("D:\\161413070_00-76-150-1803_FIP_170109.pdf");
if(datei.exists())
{
    try(PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(datei)) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(doc));
        if(job.printDialog())
        {
            job.print();
        }
        doc.close();

    }catch(InvalidPasswordException ivpwe)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(WinScanJ.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ivpwe);
    }
    catch(IOException | PrinterException ioe)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(WinScanJ.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioe);
    }
}
```

The program is opening the print dialog which is fine and it seems to send out a print job. I can see a Print Job in the print queue in windows for about a second, but the printer isn`t printing something.
I have a network printer here and it works fine.
I guess my program is sending an empty print advice, but don`t know why. The specified PDF Document exists and isn`t empty.
Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advice
TDO

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I found the problem. fontbox.jar was missing.

Comment: That should have brought a log output, so you might want to improve the configuration.

Comment: Now that it is solved, please delete your question or answer it yourself. It would be interesting to see why you didn't see the message - was it a bad configuration or did you forgot to look at it because of "not enough coffee"? :-)